# Is antimatter positron-electron pair creation and annihilation happens instantaneously or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, antimatter

This kind of transition from matter to energy(gamma) takes time (continuous in microseconds like quantum jump) or it's "instant"?

Answer (score 0):

The most precise answer would be to say we don't surely know, however terms annihilation and creation are referred to those processes which are simultaneous

One way to get your head around it is to think matter no different from energy. This way your question will reduce to "does one form of energy (electron and positron) transforms the other form (photon) simultaneously?". You shouldn't think of a classical example though, otherwise this picture won't give you a good intuition.

In case if you're wondering the lifetime of an electron-positron state

> The mass of positronium is 1.022 MeV, which is twice the electron mass minus the binding energy of a few eV. The lowest energy orbital state of positronium is 1S, and like with hydrogen, it has a hyperfine structure arising from the relative orientations of the spins of the electron and the positron.
> The singlet state, $^1S_0$, with antiparallel spins (S = 0, M_s = 0) is known as para-positronium (p-Ps). It has a mean lifetime of 0.12 ns and decays preferentially into two gamma rays with energy of 511 keV each (in the center-of-mass frame).

Comment: Interesting, the latest discoveries in electron jump are showing that the electron state transition is in microseconds and not an instant magic yet no one knows if this behavior also applies to the case of antimatter annihilation/creation? if it does then theoretically everything would look like a smooth gradient like transition from ball particle to wave and spreed in a short time span.

Comment: However, in case of instant quantum magic then perhaps there could be a third state between both states that we can't measure or do anything with it but its there? such third state will be somewhere in the  "out of time space realm" and we all know that deeper we go to the quantum world the stranger it gets, because time space and its rules are not there anymore (quantum eraser) so such third state could exist?

Comment: Why do you think there should be an intermediate step between two states and in case of annihilation/creation?

Comment: When electron and positrons meet and convert (mass) into gamma waves this conversion process shouldn't happen in our space time world/realm, does space time allow something to disappear and reappear at instant with no time? I don't think so, the conversion must take place in some other quantum dimension free of time and space rules, (out of space time grid) AFAIK space-time is "physical" and not friendly for quantum ghosts and teleport magic (that's why quantum entanglement "scary action at distance) is probably an illusion and that's why it does not allow for real information transfer)

Comment: Regarding your first question: universe allows virtual particles to be created and annihilated continuously by following $\Delta E \Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$. You can easily check the time it takes for them to annihilate. Some other quantum dimension? This sounds like an opinion based statement. Additionally, entanglement is not an illusion and one should always avoid making such bold claims.

Comment: Yes, the virtual particles can be created and annihilated and I can check their overall lifetime but can I also know how much time their exact "collapse moment" takes? or in other words, can I observe how their mass grows or decrease in time when they come and gone? I guess, I can't because that happens at instant, right? 
By entanglement as illusion I meant only the theoretical information transfer portion of entanglement as illusion so you can't make radio like device out of entanglement, can you?

Answer (score 0):

If the transition were not instantaneous there would some intermediate state between the photons emerging and electron and positron disappearing. There is no such intermediate. state, so the transition occurs instantaneously. When (and if) the transition occurs depends on the photon and electron quantum fields describing the situation.

Comment: Perhaps there is a state between? or rather its fast and gradient like transition from a particle to gamma wave in microseconds  and it's hard to measure it, just like in electron jump.

Comment: @JanPapiesz I think that the transition itself doesn't take time. When one speaks of a transition time it is meant how long it takes on average for the transition to occur.

Comment: so it's instant magic or so short that we can't detect.

Comment: @JanPapiesz I'll stick to instant magic... I find it harder to imagine that the electron vanishes while a photon appears (non-instantaneously).

Comment: For me it's not hard to imagine a smeared electron turned in to a probabilistic wave of energy, gradient stuff, or like an ice cube turning into steam in super short time. But I like the instant stuff more, its more badass.

Comment: @JanPapiesz That's how I like to hear it!